# Read line from file and add that to the same line of another file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, gnuplot

I have one file like this:

```
aaa
bbbb
c
```

And another one like this:

```
1  1241
2  301094209
3  432423
```

I want this:

```
1  1241 aaa
2  301094209 bbbb
3  432423 c
```

so I can plot it with Gnuplot. If you know how to plot it without doing this manipulation I would like to know also, but I want to know how I could do the thing I want to do also :)

Answer (score 4):

```
paste -d " " file2 file1
```

Output:

```
1  1241 aaa
2  301094209 bbbb
3  432423 c
```

---

`-d LIST`: reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the command paste is what you are looking for?

```
paste file0 file1
```

This will print, in sequence, each line of `file0`, followed by the
matching line of `file1`. The default separetor is a tab, but that can
be changed with `-d` if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

try `paste`. From man page: write  lines  consisting  of the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.  With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.